Should a Javascript Event Listener be removed before an element is unmounted in VueJS?
I have a simple vuejs directive that adds an event listener to the DOM element when its mounted. My question is, do I really need to remove that event listener before the element is unmounted later? The element will end up being removed from the DOM anyway, but does leaving the listener in place continue to consume memory?
My directive is below. If I don't need to cleanup the event listener, it would simplify it even more.
/**
 * Show a confirmation popup when the element is clicked.
 */
const NAME = 'vConfirm'
let id     = 0;
export default {
    beforeMount(el, binding) {
        id++;
        // save event handler on element, so it can be cleaned up when its unmounted; is this even needed since the
        // element is being removed from the DOM when it's unmounted?
        el[`${NAME}${id}`] = (e) => {
            const message = binding.value || 'Are you sure?';
            if (!window.confirm(message)) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        }
        el.addEventListener(binding.arg ?? 'click', el[`${NAME}${id}`], true);
    },
    beforeUnmount(el, binding) {
        el.removeEventListener(binding.arg ?? 'click', el[`${NAME}${id}`])
        delete el[`${NAME}${id}`];
    }
}


What's the purpose of id, is it a counter? I suspect storing it in an instance would be safer, module scope can be affected by hot reload. Otherwise it's ok

Since your event listener isn't referenced in outer scopes, it will be garbage collected.
But Vue doesn't favor using directives since they are DOM centric but Vue is VDOM centric.
So you could consider to create a component like this:
VUE SFC PLAYGROUND
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Confirm from './Confirm.vue';

function navigate(msg){
  alert(msg + '...');
}

const agreed = ref(false);

</script>

<template>
  <div class="links">
    <confirm :is-valid="agreed" @close="agreed = false">
      <template #prompt><label>
        <input v-model="agreed" type="checkbox">I agree</label></template>
      <a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com" @click="navigate('Opening stackoverflow')">Open stackoverflow</a>
      <a target="_blank" href="https://vuejs.org" @click="navigate('Opening vuejs.org')">Open vuejs.org</a>
    </confirm>
  </div>
</template>

Confirm.vue
<script setup>
import {useSlots, ref, mergeProps} from 'vue';

defineProps({
  isValid:{type: Boolean, default: true}
});
const $emit = defineEmits(['close']);

const $slots = useSlots();
const $dialog = ref();

let confirmed = false;
let target = null;
const render = () => {
  return $slots.default().map(vnode => (vnode.props = mergeProps({onClick}, vnode.props ?? {}), vnode));
};

function onClick(e){
  if(confirmed){
    confirmed = false;
    return;
  }
  $dialog.value.showModal();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  target = e.target;
}

function confirm(){
  confirmed = true;
  cancel();
  setTimeout(() => target.click());
}

function cancel(){
  $emit('close');
  $dialog.value.close();
}

</script>

<template>
  <render/>
  <dialog ref="$dialog">
    <slot name="prompt">Are you sure?</slot>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button :disabled="!isValid" @click="confirm">Yes</button>
      <button @click="cancel">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </dialog>
</template>


You answered the basic question and provided a great alternative. In my simple use-case your  component is a bit overkill, however it opened my eyes to some possibilities that I may tinker with in the future. Thanks.
